# Problems with javascript in oracle adf application

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle, oracle-adf

I have a strange problem. I have a custom JS file written and all of its functions work fine until I run any ADF's JS action. For example - I have an action which slide down a component and it's fine. But when I run a adf popup or Faces Error Message all of my custom JS are disabled. Where is the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ask in [OTN Community] (https://community.oracle.com/community/developer/english )They are experts in `ADF` who may help you

Answer (score 0):

Since you ain't giving any details on your problem, I can give only common answer.

When using custom js, you should always keep in mind, that any ADF action may overwrite all or part of html code on the page.
You should always set property `clientAttribute=true` for component, if you accessing it via js. Use `actionListener` instead of regular js handlers on component if possible or each time component refreshes you should reinitilize all of your js hooks. 
Good way to avoid problems is to do all you can via ADF JS framework.

Check with any js debugger(like firebug) whats going on the page during your action and act accodingly.

You can get more info in [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24382_01/web.1112/e16181/af_arch.htm).